# PHP return array as NULL after foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, null, return

I don't know why my function always returns NULL. The var_dump($args) before return shows too much items in $args. But when I call this function in another place it returns NULL. Can someone help me? Thanks.

In the commemt I explain the situation.

```
function LBE_result_hompage_search_ecole_map()
{
    //  Get department code when user click map
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    // Query data from database
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'utils_ville';
    $query = "SELECT nom_ville,code_postal FROM ".$table_name." WHERE departement=%d";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, $code) );

    $args = array();

    foreach($results as $result):
        $arg = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => 10,
            'orderby'          => 'post_date',
            'order'            => 'DESC',
            'post_type'        => 'ecole',
            'post_status'      => 'publish',
            'meta_query'       => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'ecole_ville',
                    'value' => $result->nom_ville,
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'ecole_post',
                    'value' => $result->code_postal,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );
        $args[] = $arg;
    endforeach;
    var_dump($args);  // Here shows so many items in $args
    return($agrs);
}
$args = LBE_result_hompage_search_ecole_map();
var_dump($args);  // Here shows NULL. I don't know why...
```

Comment: You have `args` and `agrs` in your function

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very sorry and even can't forgive my such low-level errors. I think a good developer starts from small things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your return statement.

`return($agrs);` should be `return($args);`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very sorry and even can't forgive my such low-level errors. I think a good developer starts from small things.

Comment: @Newbeeee No worry. Sometimes, you need an external eye to notice such error.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is not a function. Also, you put agrs not args.

Change `return($agrs);` with `return $args;`

`"Note: Note that since return is a language construct and not a function, the parentheses surrounding its arguments are not required. It is common to leave them out, and you actually should do so as PHP has less work to do in this case."`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: `return` can be used as a function by the way

Comment: it shouldn't be, yes but it is (or can be used as) a function

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. You correct my mistake and taught me more. Very grateful, really.